# Modify compareTo in Android

Tags: java, android, numbers, compareto, letters

I am using the following compareTo-Method (in this case for two strings)

```
Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                return a.compareTo(b);
            }
        });
```

in my current Android-Project.
The compareTo-Function sets special characters like `#'.` and numbers before letters. Can I modify `compareTo` somehow, that letters are before numbers and numbers before special characters ***simple as possible***?
Or do I need to write the compare-method by my own?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try making a custom method by modifying the original source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: To deviate from strings being compared by their characters' ASCII values, you will need to loop through the characters of the strings yourself and apply your custom logic there in the `Comparator`'s `compare` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override compareTo() method of String, but you can definitely provide your own Comparator with a custom compare() method in relevant places such as Collections.sort(). Remember that String compareTo() does a *lexicographic* comparison. [More information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) in Java String class documentation.

Is your need just about reversing the compareTo() output? Then a compare() method as simple as the following could work (notice the Java unary - operator):

```
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return (- a.compareTo(b));
        }
```